# Why is navigator.push not working in my flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, bloc, statefulwidget

I am building a flutter web app. I have a widget which I control with cubit, depending on if the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in, I displa his profile picture as a dropdown button, and if he selects option A i want to push him to a different page. For some reason, the Navigator isn't doing anything. This is the code for my dropdown button:

```
                  MouseRegion(
                cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                child: DropdownButton(
                  underline: SizedBox.shrink(),
                  icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
                  hint: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL.toString()),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  items: [
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        onTap: () {
                          print('tap');
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => UserPage(user)));
                        },
                        value: dropdownValue,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [Text('a'), Icon(Icons.ac_unit)],
                        )),
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: menuItem,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [Text('b'), Icon(Icons.access_alarms)],
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

This is the code for the page I want to push to:

```
import 'package:ez_user_side/cubit/cubit/sign_in_cubit.dart';
import 'package:ez_user_side/pages/page_components/Menu.dart';
import 'package:ez_user_side/pages/page_components/colors.dart';
import 'package:ez_user_side/pages/page_components/right_side.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:ez_user_side/pages/page_components/user_middle.dart';

class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;
  UserPage(this.user);
  @override
  _UserPageState createState() => _UserPageState();
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 100 * 13.46,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Menu(),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              AccountTab()
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the selected value of the `DropdownButton`. You can do that with a simple variable in a  `StatefulWidget`. Here the variable  `value` is used to determine which item is selected. Whenever some  `DropdownMenuItem` is selected you update the variable with the selected  `DropdownMenuItem`'s value.

After that, all you need is to react changes in the `DropdownButton`'s  `onChanged:(value)` callback to redirect to some other page or do something else.

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Solution extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SolutionState createState() => _SolutionState();
}

class _SolutionState extends State<Solution> {

  String value = "home";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            value: value,
            underline: SizedBox.shrink(),
            icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
            hint: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL.toString()),
            ),
            onChanged: (value) async{
              setState(() {
                if(value == 'home') {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => UserPage())
                  );
                }
                else {
                  //DO SOMETHING
                }
              });
            },
            items: [
              DropdownMenuItem(
                  onTap: ()  {
                    setState(() {
                      value = 'home';
                    });
                    print('tapped home');
                  },
                  value: 'home',
                  child: Row(
                    children: [Text('a'), Icon(Icons.ac_unit)],
                  )
              ),
              DropdownMenuItem(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      value = 'alarm';
                    });
                    print('tapped alarm');
                  },
                  value: 'alarm',
                  child: Row(
                    children: [Text('b'), Icon(Icons.access_alarms)],
                  )
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```